# Recurring certificate "Secutiry alert" on Windows

Tags: windows, security, certificate

Windows 10 is showing me a security alert windows again and again and again.
If say

```
The identity of the web site or the integrity of its connection cannot be verified.

~Certificatte was issued by a company that you have chosen not to trust.
~Security certificate date valid.
~Name on certificate is invalid or does not match the name of the site
~The security certificate has a strong signature.

Do you want to proceed?
```

I click "View Certificate"

```
This CA Root certificate is not truster. To enable trust, install this certificate in Trusted Root Certificate Authorities store.

Issued to: ORname_Jungo: OpenRG Products Group
Issued by: ORname_Jungo: OpenRG Products Group
Valid from 03/06/2004 to 29/05/2024
```

I tried to use Fiddler to see if I could find site is being contacted but when Fiddler is open I don't get the alert, I get it again immediately after I close Fiddler. (I not an experimented Fiddler user so this may be a normal behaviour, or not, I don't know.)

---

Another possible source of explanation is that I have this Internet modem: http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/Modem_BBox-2

> It's a Sagem F@st 3464 (even if the box looks different), running a
>   customized version of Jungo Openrg.

Comment: If you want to avoid the warning, then add the certificate, to the Certificate Store.  You have a process attempting to access the domain.  We can’t help find it (based on the information you provided).  I would just remove the malware infection instead

Comment: https://sslbl.abuse.ch/intel/438833c094f6afc864c60e4a6f57e9f4d1281411/

Comment: NO legitimate software uses that certificate by the way.  It’s been blacklisted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: @Ramhound : Yes, I seen that blacklisted page and I guessed the same conclusion, though I'm not quite sure what this list is and if it's universal.
"We can’t help find it (based on the information you provided)." -> I was hoping for a way to provide more info.

Comment: Another possible source of explaination is that I have this Internet modem: http://wiki.yobi.be/wiki/Modem_BBox-2. "It's a Sagem F@st 3464 (even if the box looks different), running a customized version of Jungo Openrg"

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're running that? Your modem might be acting as MITM. If you're setup is like that for a reason consider (at least) changing  the certificates.

Comment: It's my Internet provider's modem. Not that most recent one. I'm not sure if I can use another one than those they provide.

Comment: I just contacted my ISP, they will send me the next version (BBox-3).
@Seth: what ido you mean by modem acting as MITM? I guess it's "Man in the middle", but would that mean it's "infected" or not?

Comment: That would depend on what it's supposed to do. For instance, if it's supposed to act as a virus scanner for SSL traffic it might be an intended feature. If it's not it might be infected. Do you have more than just one device that is having that issue? If not, it's likely an issues specific to your machine rather than your network.

Comment: So far I only saw the issue on one computer. Not on the second and third PCs running Win7, nor on mobiles (Androids). They ALL have NOD32. But I though it may also be a difference in detecting the issue, maybe Win10 detects "more". However this, morning I don't see the alert anymore for now.

Comment: NOD32 is notorious for performing its own man in the middle attack